# Why does KeyboardEvent.target object return false on "is" condition comparing it to its type?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, actionscript

I have a custom skinned spark's RichEditableText component. And I have a listener for keyboard events in my application for some custom hotkeys. I wanted to skip those hotkeys if I'm writing into the RichEditableText so I've added this:

```
if (event.target is RichEditableText) {
    return;
}
```

But for some reason that didn't work. So I used getQualifiedClassName(event.target) and got **spark.components::RichEditableText**. I have it imported like this:

```
import spark.components.RichEditableText;
```

Why could the original conditional not work?

**EDIT:**

Here is more thorough logging:

```
log.info("event.target is RichEditableText " + (event.target is RichEditableText));
log.info("event.target instanceof RichEditableText " + (event.target instanceof RichEditableText));
log.info("event.target.constructor == RichEditableText " + (event.target.constructor == RichEditableText));
log.info("Class(getDefinitionByName(getQualifiedClassName(event.target))) == RichEditableText " + (Class(getDefinitionByName(getQualifiedClassName(event.target))) == RichEditableText));
log.info("event.target actually is " + getQualifiedClassName(event.target));
```

And the results:

```
false
false
false
true
spark.components::RichEditableText
```

For some reason only the slowest and the most complex method worked. I can use it, but if somebody could share their thoughts on why others don't work, that would be great.

Comment: try event.CurrentTarget

Comment: `FlexSprite` (the base of all Flex components) overrides `toString()` to output the location of the sprite in the display tree. `event.target is RichEditableText` *will* be true if the target is a `RichEditableText` instance.

Comment: How exactly do you test all these? How do you do the logging?

Comment: @Aaron, please check my EDIT part of the question. getQualifiedClassName(event.target) returned spark.components::RichEditableText yet event.target is RichEditableText returns false. Any idea why could that be? Thanks for the toString() comment, I'll update the question now.

Comment: Your code is looking good and should work, maybe posting the full code will help

Comment: @Philarmon, unfortunatelly it's a big a** proprietary software I have to bugfix so it's not possible to post more.

Comment: Ok, i see that your first log saying that (is RichEditableText) = false but qualified class name is RicheditableText. A mystery :) Try log.info("className is " + event.target["className"]); Or set a breakpoint and examine the event object - what is the type you see there as target ?

Comment: Are you importing `spark.components.RichEditableText` or some other `RichEditableText`?

Comment: @Aaron, as I've mentioned in question body, I indeed import spark.components.RichEditableText. I've endedup using this as a conditional which is very weird but at least it works:
(getQualifiedClassName(event.target) == getQualifiedClassName(RichEditableText)

Comment: Indeed, I missed that. Well I've never seen this behavior, it seems like at runtime there are two different classes with the qualified name of `spark.components.RichEditableText`, which doesn't seem possible.

Comment: This could happen when the listener and the source of the event are in different application domains. This way you can have exactly the same qualified names, but different classes behind them. `getDefinitionByName()` uses the current application domain of the scope you are calling it from, so you are comparing the class you have in current domain with `RichEditableText` reference, which is also in current domain, which naturally yields true. This might be the answer, I believe.

Comment: @NoxNoctis - please post it as an answer as this seems to be the truth :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could happen when the listener and the source of the event are in different application domains. This way you can have exactly the same qualified names, but different classes behind them.

`getDefinitionByName()` uses the current application domain of the scope you are calling it from. So, in the only successful log line you are comparing the class you have in current domain with `RichEditableText` reference, which is also in current domain, which naturally yields true.